# RegEx Get country code from locale string

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to retrieve country code from locale string.

`/^([a-z]{2})-([A-Z]{2})$/` this work with fixed size locale code but not with dynamic. I know country code is at the end two character delimited by dash.

Code :

```js
const REG = /^([a-z]{2})-([A-Z]{2})$/;
getCountryCode(code) {
    var match = code.match(REG)
    if(!match || match.length < 1) return ''
    return match[1]
  }
```

Inputs ==> Expected output

```js
en-US ==> US 
quc-Latn-GT ==> GT
sw-KE ==> KE
en ==> ''
```

Comment: Did check if there is a spec for country codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the second part always start with an uppercase A-Z, you could use a single capturing group with a repeating part:

```
^[a-z]{2,}(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*-([A-Z]{2})$
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/odYbbO/1)

You can change the character classes and quantifiers accordingly to what you would allow to match.

```js
let REG = /^[a-z]{2,}(?:-[A-Z][a-z]*)*-([A-Z]{2})$/;

function getCountryCode(code) {
  var match = code.match(REG)
  if (!match) return ''
  return match[1]
}
[
  "en-US",
  "quc-Latn-GT",
  "sw-KE",
  "en"
].forEach(s => console.log(getCountryCode(s)));
```

Answer (score 5):

Using [`Intl.Locale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/Locale/Locale)

```js
function getCountryCode(code) {
  return new Intl.Locale(code).region || ''
}

console.log(getCountryCode('en-US'))
console.log(getCountryCode('quc-Latn-GT'))
console.log(getCountryCode('sw-KE'))
console.log(getCountryCode('en'))
```

Comment: although this doesn't answer the question of "using RegEx" but It's recommended

Comment: Thanks, your solution work but I was searching for RegEx